# Flutter Web - Icons not showing up when Hosted

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I found this link
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32540#issuecomment-491498679
and tried out the fix but sadly it didn't work for me.

Hoping you can help!!

Thanks
[image]

also I'm using aws amplify hosting using this setting

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
      - git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable --depth 1
      - export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build commands
    build:
      commands: 
      - flutter build web -t ./lib/main.dart
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: build/web
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths: []
```

Comment: You used simple Icon also [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html) its work for me

Answer (score 1):

Flutter web doesn't support images of SVG format. Please use png instead.

Comment: I'm using the default Icon(Icons.foo) from material hmmm

Comment: Did you include material icon.ttf in the web folder?

Comment: what is that :)

Comment: In the link that you have posted in the question it is mentioned to add materialicon.ttf. You may have to include this in your web folder for icons to work in flutter web. It's a known limitation. Easiest way around is to use a png.